# How to verify signature of refreshed id_token in Azure active directory

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid

We are using Azure active directory Oauth code flow to authenticate the user. 
We got the access_token, id_token and refresh_token using code(got it on redirect URL). 
We are using id_token to authorization each request after successful authentication and we can verify JWT using the public key which we got from `/discovery/v2.0/keys` api.

Now, JWT will expire after 1 hour. so we need to refresh this id_token.

I am refreshing id_token using below cURL

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'client_id=client%20id&refresh_token=refesh%20token%20&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=client_secret&scope=openid
```

In the response of this API, we got the access_token, refresh_token, id_token, but if you observe id_token, it does not contain JWT signature (the third part of JWT), without signature we can not verify JWT

[image: sample response of refresh token API]

We can not find any document reference why id_token is not having a signature part.
Is there any other way to refresh id_token?
Is there any workaround if id_token can not be refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases an Id token may be returned without a signature, especially if it is acquired through a back-channel with a client secret.
You already are getting the token through an encrypted channel, from the authority.
If someone was able to inject something there, they would be able to direct your app's requests for OpenID metadata as well, replacing the signing keys your app expects.
Thus the signature would not add much value here.

In addition, you won't send the Id token to any API as Id tokens should not be used for authorization.
That's what access tokens are for :)

The OpenID Connect spec has this to say: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation

> If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in this flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature. The Client MUST validate the signature of all other ID Tokens according to JWS [JWS] using the algorithm specified in the JWT alg Header Parameter. The Client MUST use the keys provided by the Issuer.

But then, interestingly mentions this as well: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken

> ID Tokens MUST be signed using JWS and optionally both signed and then encrypted using JWS and JWE respectively, thereby providing authentication, integrity, non-repudiation, and optionally, confidentiality, per Section 16.14. If the ID Token is encrypted, it MUST be signed then encrypted, with the result being a Nested JWT, as defined in [JWT]. ID Tokens MUST NOT use none as the alg value unless the Response Type used returns no ID Token from the Authorization Endpoint (such as when using the Authorization Code Flow) and the Client explicitly requested the use of none at Registration time.

So.. it could be that Azure AD is not compliant with spec?

EDIT: The v1 endpoint of Azure AD is not compliant in this regard. The newer v2 endpoint is fully OpenID Connect compliant.

Comment: Thanks, let's say I sent access_token to UI application after authentication, now the user application will send access_token to my backend application. How can I verify this access_token? I can not call graph API using this access_token  as the scope is openid

Comment: You should acquire the access tokens from your UI application though? And their scope should be valid scopes for your API. Your API can validate the signature of an access token as those will always be signed.

Comment: Updated my answer with some quotes from the OpenID Connect spec. The first one discusses the fact that TLS allows you to confirm the issuer in the refresh scenario. But the spec also mentions that Id tokens must be signed. So in that way Azure AD might be going against the spec.

Comment: I talked with a member of the Azure AD team about this. This only happens in certain cases when using the v1 token endpoint. The v2 endpoint on the other hand is fully OpenID compliant, so the ID tokens there will always be signed.

Comment: Thanks, After changing to endpoint to `/oauth2/v2.0/token ` I am getting full JWT in id_token and access_token. How can i verify signature of access_token? Or my application should only verify signature of id_token.

Comment: You only need to verify the tokens meant for you. In this case that's the id token. The access token should be verified by the API that you send it to.